# How can I check if edittext is empty?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-edittext, bundle

I have two edittexts and a calculate button. I will enter two numbers and I want to sum these two numbers when I click on the calculate button.Then,  when I click on the button, I want to show this result in another activity through bundle. However, if these edittexts are empty, I take a error such as this app stopped. How can I solve these problem? Thank you ...

```
float number1,number2;
 float resultNet;

                Bundle  bundle = new Bundle(); 
                number1 = Float.parseFloat(edittext1.getText().toString());
                number2 = Float.parseFloat(edittext2.getText().toString());


if((!"".equals(edittext1)) && (!"".equals(edittext2)))
                {
                   // result = number1 - number2/4;
                    //bundle.putFloat("resultNet",resultnet); 


                    Intent intent = new Intent(Calculations.this,CalculationsResults.class);
                    intent.putExtras(bundle);
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
                else 
                {
                    resultNet = number1 - number2/4;
                    bundle.putFloat("resultNet",resultnet); 


                    Intent intent = new Intent(Calculations.this,CalculationsResults.class);
                    intent.putExtras(bundle);
                    startActivity(intent);



                }
```

```
resultCalculation = findViewById(R.id.result);
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
       float resultNet = bundle.getFloat("resultNet");
 if(bundle!= null)
        {

            resultCalculation.setText("Sum Result:"+ resultNet);



        }
```

Comment: Think about what type `edittext1` is.

Comment: All edittexts are float.

Comment: that makes no sense. a) you cannot compare a `String` to a `float` and expect it to be equal and b) a float cannot be empty. Please show how you declare `edittext1` and 2

Comment: your edit shows that `edittext` is not `float`. Also `Float.parseFloat` will throw a `NumberFormatException` if the text is empty which causes your crash.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the value of the text inside of the EditText then use the values when you know they're appropriate:

```
// Get the value of the text within the EditText
String enteredText1 = myEditText1.getText().toString();
String enteredText2 = myEditText2.getText().toString();

// Use String comparison to check if the text isn't empty
if(!enteredText1.equals("") && !enteredText2.equals(""){
    // Now you know the values aren't empty
    float myVal = Float.parseFloat(enteredText1);
    float myVal2 = Float.parseFloat(enteredText2);

    // do something with the values ...
}else{
    // do something when the values are empty ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
EditText textA = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text1);
EditText textB = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text2);

String fieldText1 = textA.getText().toString();
String fieldText2 = textB.getText().toString();

if (fieldText1.matches("") || fieldText2.matches("")) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Please, Fill in all fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
return;
}
```